# Batch file - IF Error

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I need help with my if command in my file converter.
I keep changing the command a bit, but it just returns with

> (exit) was unexpected at this time.

And then it closes command prompt.
The if command is:

> if %success% == 0 (exit) else (goto converter)

Please help.

Comment: In cases like this, be sure to remove or comment out `ECHO OFF` statements so that the processing will be shown. At the end of a .bat script, you probably want `EXIT /B`. See `EXIT /?`.

Comment: If you just want to terminate the batch script and not close the command window then use `GOTO :EOF` instead of `exit`. EOF is an implicit label at the very end of any batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all probability, `success` is not assigned, ie. set to *nothing*

```
if "%success%"=="0" (exit) else (goto converter)
```

should succeed - but remember `exit` will terminate the `cmd` session...

Comment: Okay, that didn't work but i fixed it. I needed to type "if "%success%" == "0" (exit)"

Comment: I can't see a difference. Surrounding a string in backticks will shade the background, single-`*` will italicise and double-`*` make bold. May help with the quote-count.

Comment: I added spaces.

Comment: Hmm  - it might be that if you are using a word-processor like utility to edit your code the quotes may be being converted to "smart quotes". This will work after a fashion because it makes the first string non-empty, but if the contents of that string include a space (as may be set by a `set /p` command) it would fail. The quotes need to be strictly `"` as used by editors like notepad++ or editplus (amonst others). Afraid a venerable old program just doesn't quite get these new-fangled ideas. *If* this is the case as I suspect, the spaces are optional.

Comment: It was Notepad++ set to Batch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using goto use call and write exit after the if - else condition

```
set /A success=1
if %success%==0 ( exit ) else ( call :converter )
exit
:converter
echo In Conveter Function
pause
```

At the end of If-Else you must write exit otherwise converter function will be called twice